# How do I get all attachments that are used in the current post, not just the children?

Tags: attachments, images

`wp_get_attachment_url()` is the method used to fetch the attachments. Currently I am passing the attachment IDs fetched by

```
$attachments = get_children( 
    array(
        post_parent' => get_the_ID(), 
        'post_type'  => 'attachment'
    ) 
);
```

But when there are attachments used in the post that are children of another post, this code will not include them. How can I get all attachments that are actually used?